# ASUS P8Z68-V LX UEFI

Tags: windows, motherboard, uefi

Hi i'm very interested in UEFI development in operating systems. I just bought a ASUS P8Z68-V LX motherboard which says in the description 'UEFI BIOS (EZ Mode) - Flexible & Easy BIOS Interface' - TigerDirect. Is this true UEFI, can I boot Fedora in UEFI mode on this or Windows 7 x64 in UEFI mode on this, Can I drop into a shell? I really want to know I haven't got the board yet. Any answers is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a `ASRock Extreme4 Gen3` mobo on the same Intel Z68 chipset as yours. With the fancy graphics mouse-driven UEFI BIOS.

I had partitioned my 512Gb SSD with GPT, and installed Windows 7 x64 + Gentoo Linux x64.

And about shell, there is option in bios called `boot EFI shell`, but all it does is searching for file named `shellx64.efi` on all available disks (and running it, if found).

So, it does not have any integrated EFI shell. I'm sure your board has the same logic.

Comment: I figured it out and I installed Windows 7 x64 SP1 under GPT UEFI THANKSSS!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have the PRO version of this board so I don't know how different it is from your LX version.

Yes, you can boot into Windows 7 x64. (I got Windows Server 2008 R2 working fine using UEFI). You need to choose the Windows Boot Manager after selecting UEFI in the BIOS. You also need it if you have 3TB drives which I do. The BIOS is very user friendly - it even has a working mouse!

Can't tell you about Linux as my motherboard borked when I was about to install openSUSE after changing boot priority so it would boot from the installation disc! Might have been coincidence - motherboard has been replaced and computer should be back with me soon.

Don't know about dropping into a shell? Whose shell would that be? A BIOS shell?

So apart from a new board frying within 2 weeks of me having it, it's great. Cool looking too with the blue wavy heat sink fins.

Comment: I know you don't 'need' a 3TB drive it 'supports' it but I mean dropping to a UEFI shell that is loaded from the UEFI firmware and did you load Windows 7 x64 in GPT mode not MBR mode?

Comment: You can install in either but I had to use GPT otherwise it wouldn't see the full size of my disks.